# Hg: History of chunks of a (moved) file

Tags: mercurial

How can I browse the history of a chunk of a file, or the whole file if only that is possible, oven though the file was moved?

For example, file r/a/b.txt  was moved to r/b.txt but had a history while in r/a,and I would like to see that history, if possible focused on a certain chunk/set of lines of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see the history of a file with

```
hg log --follow your-file
```

This will simply list the changesets that touch the given file. You can add `--patch` if you want to see the patches along with the log messages.

I don't know of a tool that can focus on a particular hunk. The closest is the annotate command. I always use it from TortoiseHg (works on all Windows, Mac, and Linux) which allows you to right-click on a given line and annotate the parent changeset of the changeset that touched the line. That makes it really convenient to "peel off" layers of history in the file.